# Max pool operation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, imagefilter

Is there a function that allows to compute a 2d max-pooling with predefined, kernel size and window stride in Matlab?

I was looking around but couldn't find anything so far...

Say I have a 3D cube of data [HxWxC], I'd like to run a 2d max-pooling on every channel separately (similar to the max-pool operation known from neural networks).
A similar opencv function would also help me out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [matconvnet](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/install/)

```
k = 3; % kernel_size
p = 1; % padding size
data_pooled = vl_nnpool(single(data),[k,k],'Pad',[p,p,p,p]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution that doesn't require the neural network function.

You could do a convolution with your kernel on each channel and then select the slices of the resulting  matrix that you want to keep (which corresponds to the stride). Here's a code sample for a generic case of linear average pooling.

```
% pool
kernel = ones(k)/k^2;
temp = conv2(padarray(data, [p p]), kernel, 'valid');
% downsample 
pooled_data = temp(1:stride:end, 1:stride:end);
```

You could, of course, use an order statistic filter instead of the linear averaging in this example, or any other pooling function. You can also play around with the padarray value parameter to get the padding behavior you desire.